# How to use following-sibling xpath query with php?

Tags: php, xpath, siblings

XML:

```
<Routes>
  <Route type="source" >
   <Table>
     <Tablename>incoming</Tablename>
     <Fields>
       <Fieldsname ref="dest">truegoto</Fieldsname>
     </Fields>
   </Table>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

PHP:

```
$doc    = new SimpleXMLElement('routingConfig.xml', null, true);
$foo = $doc->xpath('/Routes/Route[@type="source"]/Table/Tablename[incoming]/following-sibling::Fields/Fieldsname[@ref="dest"]');
print_r($foo);
```

Trying  to get `truegoto` by way of knowing `<Tablename>incoming</Tablename>`. My current code just returns an empty array : /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the `following-sibling` part. By that point, you already have no nodes selected. This is because `Tablename[incoming]` means "`Tablename` elements that have a child element called `incoming`". You need `Tablename[.="incoming"]` instead, which tests the content of the element:

```
/Routes/Route[@type="source"]/Table/Tablename[.="incoming"]/following-sibling::Fields/Fieldsname[@ref="dest"]
```

Comment: Any manual or reference on that? Never seen that syntax before. Now that I think about it /Table[Tablename="incoming"]... Should work too

Comment: @Jared `.` means "the current item". You can see an example in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx). And yes, your alternative should work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'll accept @lonesomeday's answer, here is perhaps an easier to read alternative:

```
$foo = $doc->xpath('/Routes/Route[@type="source"]/Table[Tablename="incoming"]/Fields/Fieldsname[@ref="dest"]');
```